# A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB0, the port doesn't exist (UART bridge CP2102)

Tags: arduino-ide, uart

I can't upload my program to ESP32-CAM. It just keeps saying the port doesn't exist. But I can see it in /dev/ttyUSB0 (By the way, I'm on linux, Fedora)
The UART bridge is CP2102 Silicon Labs.

What I've tried:

- Using both IDE 1, 2
- Removing everything, trying again on IDE 1
- upgrading permissions

Any help will be appreciated.

---

[image]
[image]

After `sudo dmesg -wT | grep cp2102` as suggested by @timemage, I got this:[image]

---

Comment: Please check if your user has access rights to /dev/ttyUSB0. You can add yourself to the dialup group or take similar actions.

Comment: @gbg After Posting the question, I did come across some posts suggesting the same. I did that but it didn't help. Is there a need to install any driver of the UART (CP2102) even in Linux? I can get it to work on windows by updating the driver.

Comment: @44yu5h It's not going to be a lack of a driver unless you're running some obscure build of the kernel. Post `sudo dmesg -wT` output from the first line of after insertion downward. Besides diagnosing other options it will also allow you to convince yourself that a driver is loading when you see something like `cp210x <bus numbers>: cp210x converter detected`

Comment: @timemage Thanks for answering. I did `sudo dmesg -wT | grep cp2102` did not get anything. I didn't take a screenshot. I will update my question with the ss soon. In a lecture right now.

Comment: `grep cp2102` in not going to find `cp210x`. Anyway, I'm sure you have that. The real point of posting it is the potential to see other diagnostically useful things that grepping is only going to remove.

Comment: @timemage Yes! sorry my bad. I've attached the screenshot. Still, it returns the same error `A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB0, the port doesn't exist` The RX led is constantly on (as it was on Windows before I updated the driver, so I was just linking things but anyway) Any suggestions?

Comment: Not a good suggestion. Because it's an easy test, I would disconnect the ESP32 and perform a loopback test on the cp2102. This would at least eliminate a bunch of stuff, although pretty much everything "arduino" about your question. But on the other hand you'd be able to ask it to a wider audience of Linux users without being shunted right back here.

Comment: @timemage Actually I have 2 cp2102. Both don't work. Tried both Arduino 1 and 2. Tried removing the braille screen reader as suggested in some posts. No help. You are right, let me just ask it on linux forum. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/esp32/comments/ybzduf/took_me_1_hour_to_make_a_hello_world/) by [Bee_HapBee](https://www.reddit.com/user/Bee_HapBee/) on Reddit solved my issue! Thank you!

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

> Yep, I wish esptool.py would've told me that I needed permissions, rather than the port doesn't exist

Comment: [chmod 666](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-666/) - *"(U)ser / owner can read, can write and can't execute. (G)roup can read, can write and can't execute. (O)thers can read, can write and can't execute"*

Comment: What about the security implications? Isn't it more standard to use the *dialup* user or some [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rules?